# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un salto de línea en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

todo el contenido del body sale corrido y los saltos de línea \n\r no funcionan solo los separan, como puedo hacer un salto de línea :

```
const $form = document.querySelector('#form')
const $buttonMailto = document.querySelector('#trucazo')

    $form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit)

    function handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      const form = new FormData(this)
      trucazo.setAttribute('href', `mailto:soporte@luxurycapitaloficial.com?subject=\n
        ${form.get('nombre')}
        ${form.get('apellido')}
        &body=${form.get('nombre')}
        ${form.get('apellido')}
        ${form.get('email')}`)
      trucazo.click()
      $buttonMailto.setAttribute('href', `mailto:soporte@luxurycapitaloficial.com?
        subject=consulta de inversión de: ${form.get('nombre')}${form.get('apellido')}
        &body=Adjunto mis datos:
        Nombre:${form.get('nombre')}
        Apellido:${form.get('apellido')}
        Correo: ${form.get('email')}`)
      $buttonMailto.click()
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, pero si te refieres que ves todo junto al recibir la petición pues... así es, como quieres que se interprete los datos si hay saltos de línea??

Comment: Bienvenida a SOes, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio y obtener tu primera medalla!. También lee [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.